# Numpy higher dimension + norm

Tags: python, numpy

I found this cool piece of code `D = np.linalg.norm(X[:, None, :] - Y[None, :, :], axis=2)` and I'm quite confused as to how it works. Here `X` and `Y` are `Nxd` and `Mxd` sized matrices respectively.

I was trying to vectorize the following operation

```
 for i in range(N):
     for j in range(M):
         D[i, j] = np.linalg.norm(X[i] - Y[j])
```

and the code initially stated was able to do that. I am fairly new to Numpy and I'm confused how (1) 2D matrices were mapped up to 3D (2) how this is successfully computing the l2 norm.

I can see that through numpy magic the values are remapped into 3D, and then computed along the 2nd axis, but I don't quite see how this is the same as the above loop given that theres an entire additional dimension.

Any help understanding would be super appreciated!

Comment: With the `None` the shapes are (N, 1, d) and (1,M,d).  They `broadcast` to (N,M,d).  `norm` reduces that to (N,M) (condensing the `d` dimension.

Comment: I also suggest reading through some of the NumPy docs; they're great. For example, you could check the [broadcasting guide](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#broadcasting)